# How to configure EJB WebServices in WildFly (in ear)

Tags: java, web-services, ejb, wildfly, undertow

I have an EAR project, deployed on WildFly 10.1.0.Final
This EAR consist of some jars and wars. I have a WebService in my jar file.

I can't understand clearly how to configurate my project.
I spend a lot of time in google and debugger... so i need help )

My AIM: Set default AuthType/Security-domain for my EJB WebService in JAR on ear/server level.

For Security-domain i found configuration in:

- Standalone.xml -> subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0 (server level, HIGHT priority)
  tag: subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0
  scope: All EJB
- Standalone.xml -> subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0" (server level, Only for Undertow, HIGHT priority)
  attribute: default-security-domain (server level, medium priority)
  scope: All WebServices
- In jboss-app.xml (Medium priority!) in EAR META-INF
  Example: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/177666
  Scope: All EJB
- XML file jboss-ejb3.xml in EAR child jar project (low priority)
  http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.1.0.Final/subsystem/ejb3/index.html
  Scope: All EJB
- Security domain annotation on WebService Class:
  Annotation: org.jboss.security.SecurityDomain
  Scope: Single WebService

Also, how can i understand - ejb properties more priority for ejb beans webservices than webservices properties

But how can i set default auth metod BASIC? Without annotation on the class. I cant find (
WEB-INF/web.xml and jboss-web.xml don't affect on my webservice.

Comment: Try with `jboss-webservices.xml` descriptor. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Advanced+User+Guide#AdvancedUserGuide-Configurationthroughdeploymentdescriptor

Comment: Where is one minus, that we have from webservices schema:
<xsd:element name="ejb-name" type="xsd:token"/>
I can't use wildcard in this place. Define all ejb webservices is very redundant for us.
But thanks for this example, because someone can try this solution.
I'm waiting for other suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties from web.xml work only for war deployments.
I found only one way to configure ejb jar deployments with webservices (in one place for all endopoints and deployments).

As we know, WildFly uses **Undertow**.
We can define **Servlet Extension**: http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.2.0/#servlet-extensions

Add src/main/resources/META-INF/services/io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension.
Then, add in this file our UndertowDeploymentExtension (which implements **ServletExtension**).

Then, add in the **handleDeployment** method something like:
**deploymentInfo.setLoginConfig**( new LoginConfig( javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.BASIC_AUTH, REALM_NAME) );

Now, our jar deployments without LoginConfig will be initialized with our custom LoginConfig (and we can ommit @WebContext).
For more information you can debug at **WebMetaDataCreator.createLoginConfig** (wildfly-webservices-server-integration-10.1.0.Final.jar)

For quick preview: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/webservices/server-integration/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/webservices/tomcat/WebMetaDataCreator.java#L276

Also, you can read this suggestion from: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/undertow-dev/2016-December/001801.html

Answer (score 0):

is using maven?

In this repository https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart you can find lot of examples of projects for deploy in wildfly. Specifically for web service using ejb this example is usefull https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/jaxws-ejb. Note that in this project is necesary indicate the context root on jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/yourpath</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

And the configuration for web service is performed with annotations.

```
/**
* @author rsearls@redhat@com
*/
@Stateless
@Remote(EJB3RemoteInterface.class)
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class EJB3Bean01 implements EJB3RemoteInterface {
    @WebMethod
    public String echo(String input) {
        return "EJB3Bean01 returning: " + input;
    }
```

}